# Is it possible to 'hyperlink' text within a UILabel/TextView but activate a segue on tap of this 'hyperlink'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I say 'hyperlink' because I don't know what else to call it, and that is how i'd like it to appear.

Obviously this is possible using a combination of labels and buttons, but my labels and buttons are programmatically generated and I imagine i'd have to also programmatically arrange them, which would likely be tedious and inflexible in terms of changing font sizes etc.

Any ideas/approaches would be much appreciated!

---

As an example, look at Instagram's following and news feed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Nimbus Attributed Label](http://docs.nimbuskit.info/group___nimbus_attributed_label.html) it can provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect. Lots of other useful things in this library also - thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `userInteractionEnabled` and then add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label.